# The probability mass function given a new random variable

Tags: probability-distributions

Say the random variable $Y = X^2 + 4$.

And $P(X = -2) = 1/10, P(X = -1) = 2/5, P(X = 0) = 1/4, P(X = 1) = 1/5, P(X = 2) = 1/20$

How would you find P(Y = 8)?

Additional question:

> Say W is the number shown on a biased six-sided die. We know that
> P(W=w)=0.2 if w is an even number, and also that the probability the
> die shows a prime number is 0.5. What are the steps to finding the
> $P(X=1)$?

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: What is $P(X=2)$ at your pmf?

Comment: @callculus42 I edited the question sorry

Comment: @TingoHugo Just set $Y=8$ and then solve the equation for $X$: $8=X^2+4\Rightarrow X^2=4\Rightarrow X=2 \cup X=-2$. So $P(Y=8)=P(X=-2)+P(X=2)$.

Comment: @callculus42 oh wow that's how you do it? thanks

Comment: @TingoHugo Yes.

Comment: @callculus42 Can I trouble you with another question? Say W is the number shown on a biased six-sided die. We know that P(W=w)=0.2 if w is an even number, and also that the probability the die shows a prime number is 0.5. What are the steps to finding the P(X=1,2, etc)?

Comment: At the moment, with these information I cannot solve this question. It is asked for all values of $P(X=k)?$

Comment: no just P(X=1), that's the full question

Comment: @TingoHugo I've posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prime numbers up to 6 are $2,3,5$. So $P(X=2)+P(X=3)+P(X=5)=0.5$. And we know that $P(X=2)=0.2$. Thus  $P(X=3)+P(X=5)=0.3$.

So we know the following probabilities:

$P(X=2)=P(X=4)=P(X=6)=0.2$ and $P(X=3)+P(X=5)=0.3$

And we also know that the probability that any number is rolled is 1, which means that

$P(X=1)+P(X=2)+P(X=3)+P(X=4)+P(X=5)+P(X=6)=1$.

Finally we can insert the values to calculate $P(X=1)$.